# Saving images in mongodb as blob, React

Tags: javascript, image, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I am using the dropzone-react component to upload pictures. After uploading, it gives me the `blob:http://test` address and if I open it I can see the picture i uploaded. 
What challenges me now is that I want to save this image as a blob-type into MongoDB.

This is my current code which is called after I chose a picture to upload. The files[0].preview shows the correct URL. Also `console.log(blob)` shows the blob in the console (but I can't find a data section, maybe that is the problem?

```
onFileDrop(files) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log(files[0].preview);
    xhr.open('GET', files[0].preview, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var blob = xhr.response;
            console.log(blob);
            Database.update({_id : _stateId}, { $push : {picture : blob}});
            }
        };
    xhr.send();
```

But after I update the database the picture element is just empty in the MongoDB. I tried saving xhr.response.type and this works, but I somehow have to access the data to store it inside MongoDB and retrieve it as a picture on another line in my code.

Am I missing some crucial step or is there even an easier approach to saving images in mongoDB by using react?

I am using the meteor framework, if that's an important information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send your file to a REST endpoint of a server, and from the server you should send the image to your DB (MongoDB in this case).

[Take a look at this example](https://gist.github.com/jkomyno/667a207301dd6d7dcbe2c0130b09483b)

Answer (score 3):

I'm late to the party but instead of saving an image as blob, you could base64 encode it and then store the string in the database as plain text.

I have done this in past projects and storing a string is easier than storing/retrieving binary data in mongoDB.

The downside is that Base64 encoded binaries occupy about 37% more space than raw binaries.

[Wikipedia article about Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already submitted this project a while ago so I won't change it anymore. But this would've been a very good idea because it was just about some small images - so no problem with space occupancy.

Answer (score 1):

I use a package called vsivsi:file-collection to store files/images in Mongo.

https://atmospherejs.com/vsivsi/file-collection

It includes example apps on how to do the file saving to your db in a griefs collection.